# Pick closest color from the color array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors, color-scheme

What i am doing is i have a color and color array for example four colors (#0000ff(blue),##000033(dark blue),#ccccff(light blue),#b20000(red)) and a color (pink). I need to match the color with the closest color in my array. In my case the pink color should match the red. How can i do this? . I had a color in RGB which i am converting to Hex like this.

```
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
        rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        function hex(x) {
            return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }
        return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }
This is working fine but now i need to match the color with the color array and pick the best color.

I have found the solution.

    function getSimilarColors (color) {
        var base_colors=["0000ff","000033","ccccff","b20000"];

        //Convert to RGB, then R, G, B
        var color_rgb = hex2rgb(color);
        var color_r = color_rgb.split(',')[0];
        var color_g = color_rgb.split(',')[1];
        var color_b = color_rgb.split(',')[2];

        //Create an emtyp array for the difference betwwen the colors
        var differenceArray=[];

        //Function to find the smallest value in an array
        Array.min = function( array ){
               return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
        };


        //Convert the HEX color in the array to RGB colors, split them up to R-G-B, then find out the difference between the "color" and the colors in the array
        $.each(base_colors, function(index, value) { 
            var base_color_rgb = hex2rgb(value);
            var base_colors_r = base_color_rgb.split(',')[0];
            var base_colors_g = base_color_rgb.split(',')[1];
            var base_colors_b = base_color_rgb.split(',')[2];

            //Add the difference to the differenceArray
            differenceArray.push(Math.sqrt((color_r-base_colors_r)*(color_r-base_colors_r)+(color_g-base_colors_g)*(color_g-base_colors_g)+(color_b-base_colors_b)*(color_b-base_colors_b)));
        });

        //Get the lowest number from the differenceArray
        var lowest = Array.min(differenceArray);

        //Get the index for that lowest number
        var index = differenceArray.indexOf(lowest);


    //Return the HEX code
    return base_colors[index];
}
```

This is how to convert hex to rgb

```
//Function to convert HEX to RGB
function hex2rgb( colour ) {
    var r,g,b;
    if ( colour.charAt(0) == '#' ) {
        colour = colour.substr(1);
    }

    r = colour.charAt(0) + colour.charAt(1);
    g = colour.charAt(2) + colour.charAt(3);
    b = colour.charAt(4) + colour.charAt(5);

    r = parseInt( r,16 );
    g = parseInt( g,16 );
    b = parseInt( b ,16);
    return r+','+g+','+b;
}
```

Comment: this is a PHP solution

Comment: Really useful, a JS question links to a PHP answer using PHP specific functions.